# Session data lost between pages PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, session-variables, data-loss

I am making a news add form using post method. In the second page i make data validation. I define the variables like `$message = $_POST["message"]` and after that `$_SESSION['message'] = "$message";` after that I echo the session var and everything look fine the data appear. And when I click to send which go to another page to add the data to the DB the session vars a empty. There is session_start on every page if i define veriable like `$_SESSION="test"` it passess all 3 pages but the data generated in the form is lost. Please help!

Comment: Do you do a `session_start()`?

Comment: So you try to insert in the BDD in another page after the form was sent ?

Comment: "There is session_start on every page"

Comment: 3 pages first is the form 2-nd where I define varaiables and checking the information and the 3-th page add the data to mySQL

Comment: why the heck do you need a third page? normally you do the form on page one then you have a second page which checks the input and if the input was right it inserts the data into the DB and then redirects to a "everything_done.php" page or if the input was wrong it redirects back to the form.

Comment: the second page is for the user to verify the data he eneterd in the form and there option to correct it or send it.

Comment: I've trided to make everything in the second page using IF. But when i click send and page is reloader the data lost the same way like in the third page.

Comment: But the question is why the form data disappear and defined var like $_SESSION="test" are OK in every page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$_SESSION="test"` is overwriting all of your session data.

Instead you should do what you are doing in other places and use `$_SESSION['test']="test"`.

This will put a new item into your `$_SESSION` array instead of overwriting all session variables.